# ASP.NET MVC images and other static content url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I just edited my route for a user details page to look like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "UserDetails", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Users", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Now when my url looks like this: `localhost/Users/Details/1/ShawnMclean`
Images do not load both from the controller and the site.master. (no idea why the css and javascript had correct urls though). If the url is `localhost/Users/Details/1` then everything loads fine.

My img in `site.master` and `Details.aspx` looks like this in the old url:

```
<img src="../../Content/Images/logo3.png" />
```

but when the url gets an additional parameter, the image is actually located at `../../../Content/Images/logo3.png`

Is there a way to make images and other static content's url change?

Comment: What is the code in your site.master?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try linking your images like this:

```
<img src="/Content/Images/logo3.png" />
```

or if that doesn't work you could always use a helper for your links

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Images/logo3.png") %>" />
```

one other way could be

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/logo3.png")" />
```

Comment: I have that above all my routes.

Comment: Why did `/Content/Images/logo3.png` worked? does the first slash make it start from the site root?

Comment: `/` is for absolute (root). `../` is relative. Always try and use absolute paths. The correct way for MVC is using `Url.Content(~/)`.

Comment: The second example seems wrong. Should there really be a forward slash before `<%=Url...`?

Comment: @quakkels , hi , i am saving Imagepath in database as : `c://user/tom/images` ,  i am not able to retrieve it in view why ?

Comment: @stom: this should be a new question and someone from the SO community will gladly help. The reason your path in the database does not work is probably because you're storing a local path rather than a http based url. When a browser load you webpage with an img tag that starts with `c:/` it doesn't know how to access that. start your paths starting at the site root. So if your images are here: `http://example.com/images` then you img tag should start with `/images`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a helper:

```
<img src='<%= Url.Content( "~/Content/Images/pic.jpg" ) %>' alt="My Image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
<a href="/"><img src="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Images/logo.png")%>" alt="logo" title="Logo" /></a>
```